# RC-circuit - DE

Tags: capacitor

Yesterday I was browsing through some questions in preparation for my exam and I found this one:

> Consider the circuit below consisting out of a capacitor **C** and two identical resistors **R**. For \$t<0\$ the switch is open and the capacitor is uncharged. At \$t=0\$ switch is shut and the circuit is connected to the voltage source with constant voltage **U**.
>
> [image]
>
> a) What's the total current in the circuit immediately after the switch is shut? What's the charge of the capacitor and the total current after a very long time?
>
> b) Determine for \$t>0\$ the total current in the circuit and the charge of the capacitor as a function of time by setting up a suitable differential equation and solving it.

I didn't have an answer to that so I couldn't answer it and I don't have enough reputation yet to comment. There was answer but it wasn't explicit on b).

I had very similar problem in past exercises and I could never set up a differential equation and solve it. Could someone help me out here?

Edit: \$V_R=\frac{R}{2}\cdot I\$ and \$V_C=\frac{1}{C}\int Idt\$

With Kirchhoff's law it should be

\$\frac{R\cdot I}{2}+\frac{1}{C}\int Idt=\frac{U}{2}\$?

So differentiating with respect to t should be:

\$\frac{R}{2}\frac{dI}{dt}+\frac{I}{C}=0\$.

So that would give us \$I=\frac{2U}{R}e^{-\frac{2t}{RC}}\$, right?

But how do I get an expression for the charge on the capacitor?

Comment: charge of capacitor: \$Q = V_C C\$ with \$V_C = U/2 - V_R\$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For t≥0 you can replace the voltage source with the two Rs (forming a voltage divider) by its Thevenin equivalent.

This simplifies your circuit (for t≥0) to:

[image]

---

EDIT:
Note: In the simplified but equivalent circuit the resistor's value is R/2 and the voltage of the voltage source is U/2.

---

You should be able to formulate the differential equation for this circuit.

Comment: Could you look at my edit in the original post and see if I wrote it down correctly? And I also have trouble with the charge.

Comment: It looks good to me.

Comment: Thanks. Now I know how to deal with RC circuits and with voltage dividers. 

Although, now that I think about it, I'm kind of curious about a) of the exercise. What's the charge and the total current after a very long time? Isn't the total current just the \$I\$ we got from the differential equation? And since the current doesn't reach its maximum then the capacitor will not be fully charged?

Comment: Though the current *never* reaches a terminal value it asymtotically gets closer and closer to the "final" value 0. That value is meant (limit t--> infinity) by  "after a very long time". The same is the case with voltage and charge. After several RC time intervals those values reach 0.9999...% of the asymtotic value.

Comment: @Chu: **any** linear circuit can by replaced ("combined" to) its Thevenin equivalent (which equals a voltage source with a serial resistor). If you don't know this, please look e.g. here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem

Comment: @Curd, how can you combine the two resistors when different currents flow through them? With your circuit, the final voltage across C is U.

Comment: @Chu: No, it is U/2 (in my simplified equivalent circuit not only R has been replaced by R/2 but also U has been replaced by U/2).

Comment: @Curd, didn't see the u/2. ok

Comment: Yes, it's kind of small. I should have mentioned in the text too...